# Get Last child of node in jstree

Tags: jquery, nodes, jstree

I have a jstree which is generated something like :

```
<ul>
<li id="BA"><a href="#"> Block Address </a>
    <ul>
       <li id="SA"><a href="#">Street Address</a></li>
       <li id="C"><a href="#">City</a></li>
       <li id="P"><a href="#">Province</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I have to find the last child of the selected node, which in this case is `Block Address`. I did try using :

```
  var id = data.rslt.obj.attr("id");
   var last_child =  $("#"+id + "li:last-child").attr("id");
    alert(last_child);
```

I want to display `P` in the popout . Can someone assist me , why telling what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Add a space before li:last-child.

Comment: $("#"+id + "li:last-child") should be $("#"+id + " li:last-child")

Answer (score 1):

So i finally found a solutions , thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1586880/null and his suggestion.

i am not looking for the last last-child, but last descendant :

```
var id = data.rslt.r.attr("id");
alert($("#"+id).find("li:last-child").attr("id"));
```

thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

Add a space before `li:last-child`:

```
 $("#"+id + " li:last-child").attr("id");
             ^ - Here
```

As you are searching for the descendant `<li>` element, and your current selector would render as:

`"#<IDhere>li:last-child"`, which isn't correct.

Comment: It is giving me the id of the 1st li , i.e., `SA` maybe i'm missing something ?

Comment: how should change it, then ? Please suggest

Comment: @user2583714 What is the ID in this case? It works fine for me, I get P - http://jsfiddle.net/pLC7D/